# missing invariant in dafny code involving sequences

Tags: dafny

I am wondering if there is a reason why dafny is unable to verify my program?

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Ip1s

Am I missing some additional invariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of `s` and your construction of `o` go in "different directions". The recursive case of `s` defines `s(i)` in terms of 
`i[0]` and what is "previously" defined by `s(i[1..])`. In contrast, the loop iteration defines the new `o` in terms of `i[n]` and the previous value of `o`. It would take an inductively proven lemma to establish the proof obligations in your current program, and Dafny does not invent such lemmas by itself.

For the record in this answer, here is what you started with:

```
function s(i: seq<int>): seq<int> {
  if |i| == 0 then [] else 
    if i[0] == 42 then [i[0]] + s(i[1..])
    else s(i[1..])
}

method q (i: seq<int>) returns (o: seq<int>)
  ensures o == s(i)
{
  var n := 0;
  o := [];

  while n < |i|
    invariant n <= |i| && o == s(i[..n])   
  {
    if i[n] == 42 {
      o := o + [i[n]];
    } 
    n := n + 1;
  } 
}
```

There are four ways out.

One way out is to define a different version of `s`, call it `s'`, that recurses from the other end of the given sequence. Then, replace `s` by `s'` in your method specification and loop invariant. This is a fine solution, unless for some reason you really prefer `s`, not `s'`, in your method specification.

A second way out is to define such an `s'` and to prove a lemma that `s(i)` and `s'(i)` return the same value. This will let you keep `s` in your method specification, at the cost of having two function definitions and having to write (and prove and use) a lemma.

A third way out is to change the loop to iterate "downward" instead of "upward". That is, start `n` at `|i|` and decrement `n` in the loop body. (As usual, an increment of `n` is typically best done at the end of the loop body (post-increment), whereas a decrement of `n` is typically best done at the beginning of the loop body (pre-decrement).)

A fourth way out is to change the way you write the loop invariant about `o`. Currently, the invariant speaks about what you already have computed, that is, `o == s(i[..n])`. You can instead write the invariant in terms of what is yet to be computed, as in `o + s(i[n..]) == s(i)`, which you can read as "once I have added `s(i[n..])` to `o`, I will have `s(i)`". Here is that version of `q`:

```
method q(i: seq<int>) returns (o: seq<int>)
  ensures o == s(i)
{  
  var n := 0;
  o := [];

  while n < |i|
    invariant n <= |i| && o + s(i[n..]) == s(i)
  {
    if i[n] == 42 {
      o := o + [i[n]];
    } 
    n := n + 1;
  } 
}
```

You may also be interested in watching [this episode of Verification Corner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLQo5d3hI4M) on this subject.

Rustan